# multiple i2c can't work with arduino uno

Tags: arduino, i2c

I am trying to connect 2 I2C modules to arduino uno. GY86(HMC5883L,MS5611,MPU6050) and BMP085 or any other I2C module. When i test each one separately it works ok but when both are connected to the I2C bus port, Every thing ruins. th moment i connect the BMP module, GY86 starts to output wrong numbers. I also tested my GY86 with DS1307 module. same thing happens and the moment i connect them, the DS starts to output wrong random output. i tried to apply a pull up resistor for SDA and SCL but didn't work. Whats the problem?

Comment: Seems the board has MPU6050, not MPU5611

Comment: yes thanks:) type error

Answer (score 3):

## I2C at the Hardware Level

### Signals

Each I2C bus consists of two signals: SCL and SDA. SCL is the clock signal, and SDA is the data signal. The clock signal is always generated by the current bus master; some slave devices may force the clock low at times to delay the master sensing more data.

Unlike UART or SPI connections, the I2C bus drivers are "open drain", meaning that they can pull the corresponding signal low, but cannot drive it high. Thus, there can be no bus contention where one device is trying to drive the line high while another tries to pull it low, eliminating the potential for damage to the drivers or excessive power dissipation in the system. Each signal line has a pull_up resistor on it, to restore the signal to high when no device is asserting it low.

Resistor selection varies with devices on the bus, but a good rule of thumb is to start with 4.7k and adjust down.

### Signal Levels

Since the devices on the bus don't actually drive the signals high, I2C allows for some flexibility in connecting devices with different I/O voltages. In general, in a system where one device is at a higher voltage level than another, it may be possible to connect the two devices via I2C without any level shifting circuitry in between them. The trick is to connect the pull_up resistor to the lower of the two voltages. This only work in some cases, where the lower of the two system voltages exceeds the high-level input voltage of the higher voltage system - for example,  a 5V Arduino and a 3.3V accelerometer.

## Protocol

Communication via I2C is more complex that with UART or SPI solution. The signalling must adhere to a certain protocol for the devices on the bus to recognize it as valid I2C communications.

### Basics

Messages are broken up into two types of frame: an address frame, where the master indicates the slave to which the message is being sent, and one or more data frames, which are 8-bit data messages passed from master to slave or vice versa. Data is placed on the SDA line after SCL goes low, and is sampled after the SCL line goes high. The time between clock edge and data read/write is defined by the devices on the bus and will vary from chip to chip.

### Start Condition

To initiate the address frame, the master device leaves SCL high and pulls SDA low. This puts all slave devices on notice that a transmission is about to start. If two master devices wish to take ownership of the bus at one time, whichever device pulls the SDA low first wins the race and gains control of the bus. It is possible to issue repeated starts, initiating a new communication sequence without relinquishing control of the bus to other masters.

### Address Frame

The address frame is always first in any new communication sequence. For a 7-but address, the address is clocked out most significant bit (MSB) first, followed by a R/W bit indicating whether this is a read (1) or  write (0) operation.
The 9th bit of the frame is the NACK/ACK bit. This is the case for all frames (data or address).
Once the 8 bit of the frame are sent, the receiving device is given control over SDA. If the receiving device does not pull the SDA line low before the 9th clock pulse, it can be inferred that the receiving device either did not receive the data or did not know how to parse the message. In that case, the exchange halts, and it's up to the master of the system to decide how to proceed.

### Data Frames

After the address frame has been sent, data can begin being transmitted. The master will simply continue generating clock pulses at a regular interval, and the data will be placed on SDA by either the master or the slave, depending on whether the R/W bit indicated a read or write operation. The number of data frames is arbitrary, and most slave devices will auto-increment the internal register, meaning that subsequent reads or writes come from the next register in line.

### Stop Condition

Once all the data frames have been sent, the master will generate a stop condition. Stop conditions are defined by a 0->1 (low to high) transition an SDA after a 0->1 transition on SCL, with SCL remaining high. During normal data writing operation, the value on SDA should **not** change when SCL is high, to avoid stop condition.

Comment: thanks for information ... but i couldn't  find my problem :)
مرسی:)

Comment: There is nothing important abt the code . i just copy the bmp085 example code inside the body of gy86 example. i organize it so the setup and loop works together fine. I have this problems with any different sensors so it shouldn't be the code that causes  this problem

Comment: Totally unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think several devices have same address. That's why you receive bad data. Usually I2C devices have extra pins to setup lower bits of addr. Do it and don't forget to change corresponding software definitions.

---

Update:

MPU6050 has input pin, which specifies LSB of I2C addr. You need tie this pin to high level 3.3V. Otherwise MPU6050 will have same addr as DS1307. I know it for sure, because work with both ICs a lot. To do it you need broke wire between 9nth pin of MPU6050  and Gnd. And solder it through resistor >3k to 3,3V. Or not use DS1307. From memory there is ds1302 rtc module.

You should find datasheets for all ICs you use and check what are their I2C addresses. The board consists of three parts, so you must know those 3 addresses.

Comment: How can i change the addresses? i check the addresses of GY86 and DS1307 with i2c scanner . they weren't the same. I am not an expert with this things. where can i check the other things u said?

Comment: Thanks. it helps. i will test what u said and i think i am better to use another rtc module because i am not an expert in electronics. But there is a still a question. i checked the address of each one with i2cscanner sketch.(in github) they don't seem the same! so what the point?

Comment: MP6050 and rtc ds1307 may have same addresses if MPU6050 addr pin is low. It is declared in datasheets page 15 for MPU, and page 12 for RTC.  .

Comment: Thanks a lot  i got it.